# Split Phrase in words with single quotes & comma in SQL Server using TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a search query where I use the `Like` operator to search keyword, now I need to provide user with an option to search as `exact phase` or search `all words` based on search keywords

Search Keyword = `mission to mars`

Search Query

```
 Select * from Table` WHERE  Title LIKE '%mission to mars%' OR Details LIKE '%mission to mars%'
```

Now I need to convert this query so that it search for all words from search keywords `mission to mars`

So my query should be like

```
Select * from Table` WHERE  Title IN ('mission', 'to', 'mars') OR Details IN ('mission, 'to', 'mars')
```

Can I using any SQL function break the search keyword `mission to mars` and convert it into string with each word wrapped in single quote & separated by comma example **'mission', 'to', 'mars'**

`STRING_SPLIT` could have been the solution but it works in SQL SERVER 2016 & above while I am using SQL 2014.

I can split the keyword from C# it self and pass it as **'mission', 'to', 'mars'** to stored procedure also but i am interested if i can split it in T-SQL itself

Comment: I don't think you want `IN` for this. I think you want `Title LIKE '%mission%' OR Titile LIKE '%mars%' OR...`

Comment: Would this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string

Comment: You mentioned c# in your question - so my advice would be to send the stored procedure a table valued parameter instead of a string to be splitted in T-SQL (remembering that string manipulation is not T-SQL strong suit). Should you choose to split the string in SQL, you should read Aaron Bertrand's [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I need IN as in will look for all there words if past it a string similar to 'mission', 'to', 'mars', regarding you second comment i can using C# but i am interested to know if it can be done easily in T-SQL also

Comment: `X IN('1','2','3')` is shorthand for `X = '1' OR X = '2' OR X = '3'`. Do you expect title or  details to contain only a single word?

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I need to search in Title, Details and other fields as well such as brief Description which i have not included in the question for sake of simplicity, i have to usually search keywords in 3-r fields of table

Comment: Have a read up on Full-Text Search in SQL Server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Can you split a string in SQL? Yes you can. Would you want to do it - probably not. Simple fixed delimiter string splitting SQL functions can be easily found online. I believe your case would not be simple though, as you will need to take into account punctuation, noise words etc. Full-Text Search (see @gvee comment) in SQL or C# solutions would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Full-Text is not installed on the server :( so i think easy option would to to pass it from C# itself as variable to Store Procedure

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I understand what you meant by your first comments

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate `STRING_SPLIT()`'s functionality with a recursive `CTE` that will return all the words of the phrase:

```
declare @s varchar(100) = 'mission to mars';
with 
  cte as (
    select 1 n1, charindex(' ', @s) n2
    union all
    select n2 + 1, charindex(' ', @s, n2 + 1)
    from cte
    where n2 > 0
  ),
  words as (
    select substring(
      @s, 
      n1, 
      case when n2 > 0 then n2 - n1 else len(@s) end
    ) word
    from cte
  )
select * from words;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=ed6a7cedc9aa5f4324b4136b39af3e1d).
Results:

```
> | word    |
> | :------ |
> | mission |
> | to      |
> | mars    |
```

So that you can use it like this:

```
select * from tablename WHERE Title IN (select * from words)
```

Answer (score 0):

--Create a function 'fn_split_string ' which splits a string

```
create function dbo.fn_split_string(@str nvarchar(1000),@sep nvarchar(1))
returns @tab_split  table (id int identity(1,1),str nvarchar(1000) )  
as  

begin  
declare @str1 as nvarchar(1000)  
declare @istr as nvarchar(1000)  
declare @i as integer  
set @str1=@str  
set @i=2  
while @i>0 
begin  
set @i=charindex(@sep,@str1,1)  
if @i>0  
begin  
set @istr=substring(@str1,1,@i-1)  
insert into @tab_split(str) values(@istr)  
set @str1=substring(@str1,@i+1,len(@str1))  
end  
end  
insert into @tab_split(str) values(@str1)  
return   
end
```

--You can run the function as follows

```
select * from dbo.fn_split_string ('mission to mars',' ')
```

--The following script

```
Select * from Table` WHERE  Title IN ('mission', 'to', 'mars') OR Details IN ('mission, 'to', 'mars')
```

--becomes

```
select * from Table t1 inner join dbo.fn_split_string ('mission to mars',' ') t2
on t1.title=t2.str or t1.details=t2.str
```

--hope this helps

--**

> Another Solution which avoids using loops, as "Zohar Peled" adviced

**

create table  tab_numbers (Number int);

```
with cte as (select 1 n union all select 1+n from cte where n+1 <=100)
insert into tab_numbers select * from cte
option(maxrecursion 0)

go




create FUNCTION fn_split_string_2
(
   @str       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @sep  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS @tab_split table (str  nvarchar(max))

AS
  begin
  if @sep=' ' 
  begin
    set @sep=',' 
    set @str=replace(@str,' ',',')
  end


   insert into @tab_split

       SELECT Item = SUBSTRING(@str, Number, 
         CHARINDEX(@sep, @str + @sep, Number) - Number)
       FROM tab_numbers
       WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@str))
         AND SUBSTRING(@sep + @str, Number, LEN(@sep)) = @sep
   ;
   return
   end
GO
```

Comment: I edited my answer and corrected the last script, it should be "select * from Table t1 inner join dbo.fn_split_string ('mission to mars',' ') t2
on t1.title=t2.str or t1.details=t2.str"

Comment: Please don't split strings using a loop. That's the worst possible way to do it. Read the article I've linked to in the comments to the question to find better ways to do that.

Comment: thank you for the advice, I posted another function which does not use loops

Comment: Using multi-statement table valued functions is also a terrible approach to this. Neither of the function in this answer should be used as the performance is going to be horrible for even reasonably long strings.